# Adding multiple subprojects to Play 2 framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

am using play 2 framework with java

I have added a project dependency as a sub-project

by following the tutorials

Now I want a second sub-project.

But kind of new to the scala codes in the build.scala file

can some one tell me how to ass a second sub-project.

below is my code for the build.scala file and the sub-project.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import PlayProject._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "Rub_Server"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
      // These are the project dependencies
        "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",

    )

  val subProject = Project("Com-RubineEngine-GesturePoints", file("modules/Com-RubineEngine-GesturePoints"))

    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here            
    ).dependsOn(subProject)

}
```

now I want add a second project to the build.scala file
how do I do tht 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 .dependsOn(subProject, anotherProject)
```